# ROS Groovy simulator_gazebo on OSX

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello everyone,

I am trying to install gazebo in the ROS (groovy) stack (simulator_gazebo), which I believe is still 1.3. I am compiling using clang 3.2 (actually it is based on 3.2).

At first it failed to find TBB and libxml2, which I fixed by adding their .pc files so that pkg-config could find them. Then it complained about -DMAC_OS_X_VERSION not being set, so I added

```
add_definitions(-DMAC_OS_X_VERSIONS=1080)
```

In the CMakeLists.txt. After that I believe I had some problems with gazebo using CLOCK_REALTIME, which isn't available on OSX so I replaced that with the OSX equivalent.

I have gotten a long way but now I am stuck with linking dependencies for gazebo_sensors and gazebo_physics. gazebo_sensors depends on gazebo_physics, however gazebo_physics seems to also depend on gazebo_sensors, causing a circular dependency. The dependency on gazebo_sensors for gazebo_physics did not exist, without this I was getting linking errors. Adding this link causes a circular dependency. Removing the dependency on gazebo_physics in gazebo_sensors allows it to compile gazebo_physics, but then it gets stuck with linking errors for gazebo_sensors because it is missing things from gazebo_physics there then.

I also tried compiling with gcc (4.2 and 4.7), but this gave me a whole set of different errors.

I had a similar problem with gazebo_physics and gazebo_physics_ode, gazebo_physics_ode needed to link against gazebo_physics, however gazebo_physics did not need to link against gazebo_physics_ode so I could just add the link to gazebo_physics in gazebo_physics_ode.

What can I try next? I can't seem to resolve the circular dependency that I apparently have. How come this compiles fine on Ubuntu (I assume)? Should I actually be asking this on ROS answers? I tried version 1.4 from gazebosim.org but it seems to give me the same problems.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1600/ros-groovy-simulator_gazebo-on-osx/) by [Hansg91](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/238/hansg91/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-03-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

With pull requests from @Hansg91 and help from William at OSRF, I've made a [homebrew formula for gazebo](https://github.com/scpeters/homebrew-gazebo/blob/master/gazebo.rb). It's still experimental. To try it:

Install [homebrew](http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/):
`ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"`

Install [Xcode command-line development tools](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329243/xcode-4-4-command-line-tools)

Install [XQuartz](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/)

Run the following commands:

`brew tap ros/groovy`

`brew tap scpeters/gazebo`

`brew install gazebo`

`source /usr/local/share/gazebo/setup.sh`

`gazebo`

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2013-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hansg91](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/238/hansg91/) on 2013-04-03**:
Sounds great :) I don't think you really need XQuartz, you might only need it because somewhere the CMakeLists.txt checks if you have it, its not building against it I believe.

**Comment by [tkoolen](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/64/tkoolen/) on 2013-04-05**:
Works perfectly so far! Thank you so much! I wish I could upvote, but I don't have enough karma for that...

**Comment by [tkoolen](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/64/tkoolen/) on 2013-04-05**:
Has anybody tried getting drcsim to work on OSX by the way?

**Comment by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) on 2013-04-05**:
XQuartz is needed to build OGRE using the home-brew formula given by the ros/groovy tap. I haven't tried building drcsim yet. There's still a problem with plugins being hard-coded as '.so' files when they're actually '.dylib' files on the mac. Also, it crashes when I insert cameras. So there's still some work left to do. I just started a wiki page to track status on OS X, feel free to add any answers threads to the list at the bottom of this page.

**Comment by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) on 2013-04-05**:
XQuartz is needed to build OGRE using the home-brew formula given by the ros/groovy tap. I haven't tried building drcsim yet. There's still a problem with plugins being hard-coded as '.so' files when they're actually '.dylib' files on the mac. Also, it crashes when I insert cameras. So there's still some work left to do. I just started a wiki page to track status on OS X, feel free to add any answers threads to the list at the bottom of this page.

**Comment by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) on 2013-04-05**:
XQuartz is needed to build OGRE using the home-brew formula given by the ros/groovy tap. I haven't tried building drcsim yet. There's still a problem with plugins being hard-coded as '.so' files when they're actually '.dylib' files on the mac. Also, it crashes when I insert cameras. So there's still some work left to do. I just started a wiki page to track status on OS X, feel free to add any answers threads to the list at the bottom of this page.

**Comment by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) on 2013-04-05**:
XQuartz is needed to build OGRE using the home-brew formula given by the ros/groovy tap. I haven't tried building drcsim yet. There's still a problem with plugins being hard-coded as '.so' files when they're actually '.dylib' files on the mac. Also, it crashes when I insert cameras. So there's still some work left to do. I just started a wiki page to track status on OS X, feel free to add any answers threads to the list at the bottom of this page.

**Comment by [Hansg91](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/238/hansg91/) on 2013-04-08**:
Well it is very nice to see that you picked up this task, I don't need gazebo anymore at the moment (intended to use it for navigation, but I am using Stage at the moment) but I have no doubt that for some future feature I will need it and be loving it on OSX :)

**Comment by [Andrew Hundt](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/685/andrew-hundt/) on 2014-03-28**:
Note that these instructions are now out of date. I think the current homebrew steps are: `brew tap osrf/homebrew-simulation ; brew install gazebo`

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

We incorporated the changes from a pull request by @Hansg91 and I've managed to get it compiling on my machine. I used homebrew to resolve most of the dependencies.

`brew install qt protobuf-c`

`brew tap ros/groovy && brew install ogre tinyxml`

mac already has a system install of curl, but it doesn't have a pkg-config file. a workaround:

`brew install curl`

then add the following to your bashrc (actually called .bash_profile on mac):

`export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/opt/curl/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH`

then in just needs libtar. i had to install this from source

I've managed to get the code building in branch [osx_compile_hack](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/compare/osx_compile_hack..osx#diff)

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2013-03-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hansg91](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/238/hansg91/) on 2013-03-15**:
Did you get any further than two windows that cannot be interacted with? ps. I did not need your compile hack commit to compile, why is that?

**Comment by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) on 2013-03-19**:
I didn't try to run gazebo; I was just running gzserver, but fails to find all the correct libraries. I think we need to remove references to X11 and glx in [RengerEngine.cc](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/ea04fc0a86449c181fffba40c04258b7a5356bd5/gazebo/rendering/RenderEngine.cc?at=osx) and also link against Cocoa so that it will run natively in OSX.

**Comment by [Hansg91](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/238/hansg91/) on 2013-03-20**:
Yes that would be a much better solution, but I never worked with Cocoa so I have no idea how to do this, do you? If so, that would be perfect. Do you have the gzserver running by the way? For me it is stuck on Waiting for master, so I run the server on a Parallels Ubuntu and connect to that one ...